# Javascript Prototype Programming

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to include some namespace into my Javascript API.

Here's what I have so far:

```
if (!Sample || Sample == "undefined")
    var Sample = {};

Sample.SomeApi = {};

Sample.SomeApi.prototype = {
    SomeMethod: function() {
        alert('some api');
    }
};
```

What's going on here?

When I'm calling `Sample.SomeApi.SomeMethod();` // it won't work as it will complain:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'SomeMethod'
(anonymous function)Course:43
onclick
```

Comment: Side note: you want `undefined` or `typeof Sample === 'undefined'` not `"undefined"`.

Comment: Well, `Sample == "undefined"` is not going to test if it is undefined, it is going to test whether `Sample` equals the string "undefined."

Comment: Good point, alternatively, he can do `Sample == undefined` but then again the whole undefined is unnecessary, that's what `!Sample` is testing for anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant `__proto__` not `prototype`, like so:

```
if (!Sample || Sample == "undefined")
    var Sample = {};

Sample.SomeApi = {};

Sample.SomeApi.__proto__ = {
    SomeMethod: function() {
        alert('some api');
    }
};

Sample.SomeApi.SomeMethod();
```

You can test it out in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/xtyyf/

But why not just this:

```
if (!Sample || Sample == "undefined")
    var Sample = {};

Sample.SomeApi = {
    SomeMethod: function() {
        alert('some api');
    }
};

Sample.SomeApi.SomeMethod();
```

It's much cleaner.

And there is the jsFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/HUuMQ/

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. That would mean that you assign SomeMethod to the prototype of {}?

Comment: Using `__proto__` works because objects do not have a `prototype`, functions do. However `__proto__` is not standard and won't work across browsers, that is what [`getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf) is for. But the second method really is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a constructor for Sample.SomeApi not assign an empty object:

```
if(typeof Sample == 'undefined')
    Sample = {};

Sample.SomeApi = function() {
};

Sample.SomeApi.prototype = {
    someMethod : function() {
            alert('some api');
    }
}

new Sample.SomeApi().someMethod();
```

Comment: how would you make it call it like this: Sample.SomeApi.someMethod(); instead of Sample.SomeApi().someMethod(); ?

Comment: Well you don't need to use the prototype if your API is only a single object. just use `Sample.SomeApi = {
    SomeMethod: function() {
        alert('some api');
    }
);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(typeof Sample == 'undefined')
        var Sample ={}
    Sample.SomeApi = function(a)
    {
        this.a =a;
    }

Sample.SomeApi.prototype.SomeMethod = function() {
        alert('some api');
    }
    var d = new Sample.SomeApi(1);
    d.SomeMethod();
```

Hope this helps you

Go through this link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)